# Polyline Set color option for Google Api V2 getting error ?? C# Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i am getting error on the line to set polyline color option my code,

```
GEvent.addListener(polyline, "click", function() {polyline.setOptions(options: { strokeColor: 'blue' })};
```

but if i try this,

```
GEvent.addListener(polyline, "click", function() {alert("clicked");});
```

it works fine

How to set polyline color on click ??

i also try this,

```
GEvent.addListener(polyline, "click", function() {PolylineOptions({ strokeStyle: new StrokeStyle({color: 0xFF0000})});
```

it is also resulting in error HOPES for your reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up the Maps API V3 and Maps API V2 syntax.

- Maps API V2 uses setStrokeStyle not setOptions to change Polyline options
- Maps API V2 uses hex color codes (rather than 'blue' etc)

The following should work.

```
GEvent.addListener(polyline, "click", function() {
  polyline.setStrokeStyle({ color: "#FF0000" });
};
```

Comment: thanks alot u code help me out i have been sicken tired to find out the error and moake my code helpfull

Comment: one more thing i wanna ask in this post about marker if you dont mind ? how can i change my marker color too on click event ....Hopes for your suggestions

Comment: Hey Syed - Can you post it as a new Stack Overflow question? That way other people with the same problem can easily search for it. If you tag it as google-maps I'll make sure I answer it.

Comment: i have posted this in new Stack Over Flow question ...                                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170418/how-to-change-mrker-color-on-click-google-map-v2-c-web-application