# How To Change Mrker Color On Click Google Map V2 C# Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i am changing my polyline color on click my code,

```
GEvent.addListener(polyline, "click", function() {
  polyline.setStrokeStyle({ color: "#FF0000" });
};
```

How can i change the marker color on click ??

Hopes for your reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You'd need to use custom Icons to achieve that](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Icons_overview).

Same question: [How can I change the color of a Google Maps marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472957/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-google-maps-marker)

Comment: Tsar i want to change the color of mark on click ??? but the post you told me i had reviewed it but i can only create a custom mark by the help of this Link